# Namespacing the Archive Dates in Django

Tags: python, opencv

i have some Archive date in django defined in my views like this

```
class OfferingMonthArchiveView(MonthArchiveView):
  queryset=Offering.objects.all()
  date_field="date"
  allow_future=True
```

With the above class method calling the class in the url is a bit tricky

```
path('<int:year>/<int:month>/',views.OfferingMonthArchiveView.as_view(month_format='%m'),name="month-archive"),
```

but it doest seem to work, it keep bringing some error

Comment: It's `COLOR_BGR2GRAY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jasonharper wrote in a comment, OP probably meant `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`.

According to the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#gga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0a353a4b8db9040165db4dacb5bcefb6ea), the `cv2` package does not have `cv2.COLOR_BRG2GRAY`. See the link for the available color conversion codes.

For completeness, here is the relevant content from the link:

```
enum cv::ColorConversionCodes {
  cv::COLOR_BGR2BGRA = 0,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2RGBA = COLOR_BGR2BGRA,
  cv::COLOR_BGRA2BGR = 1,
  cv::COLOR_RGBA2RGB = COLOR_BGRA2BGR,
  cv::COLOR_BGR2RGBA = 2,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2BGRA = COLOR_BGR2RGBA,
  cv::COLOR_RGBA2BGR = 3,
  cv::COLOR_BGRA2RGB = COLOR_RGBA2BGR,
  cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB = 4,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR = COLOR_BGR2RGB,
  cv::COLOR_BGRA2RGBA = 5,
  cv::COLOR_RGBA2BGRA = COLOR_BGRA2RGBA,
  cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY = 6,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY = 7,
  cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR = 8,
  cv::COLOR_GRAY2RGB = COLOR_GRAY2BGR,
  cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGRA = 9,
  cv::COLOR_GRAY2RGBA = COLOR_GRAY2BGRA,
  cv::COLOR_BGRA2GRAY = 10,
  cv::COLOR_RGBA2GRAY = 11,
  cv::COLOR_BGR2BGR565 = 12,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR565 = 13,
  cv::COLOR_BGR5652BGR = 14,
  cv::COLOR_BGR5652RGB = 15,
  cv::COLOR_BGRA2BGR565 = 16,
  cv::COLOR_RGBA2BGR565 = 17,
  cv::COLOR_BGR5652BGRA = 18,
  cv::COLOR_BGR5652RGBA = 19,
  cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR565 = 20,
  cv::COLOR_BGR5652GRAY = 21,
  cv::COLOR_BGR2BGR555 = 22,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR555 = 23,
  cv::COLOR_BGR5552BGR = 24,
  cv::COLOR_BGR5552RGB = 25,
  cv::COLOR_BGRA2BGR555 = 26,
  cv::COLOR_RGBA2BGR555 = 27,
  cv::COLOR_BGR5552BGRA = 28,
  cv::COLOR_BGR5552RGBA = 29,
  cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR555 = 30,
  cv::COLOR_BGR5552GRAY = 31,
  cv::COLOR_BGR2XYZ = 32,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2XYZ = 33,
  cv::COLOR_XYZ2BGR = 34,
  cv::COLOR_XYZ2RGB = 35,
  cv::COLOR_BGR2YCrCb = 36,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2YCrCb = 37,
  cv::COLOR_YCrCb2BGR = 38,
  cv::COLOR_YCrCb2RGB = 39,
  cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV = 40,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2HSV = 41,
  cv::COLOR_BGR2Lab = 44,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2Lab = 45,
  cv::COLOR_BGR2Luv = 50,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2Luv = 51,
  cv::COLOR_BGR2HLS = 52,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2HLS = 53,
  cv::COLOR_HSV2BGR = 54,
  cv::COLOR_HSV2RGB = 55,
  cv::COLOR_Lab2BGR = 56,
  cv::COLOR_Lab2RGB = 57,
  cv::COLOR_Luv2BGR = 58,
  cv::COLOR_Luv2RGB = 59,
  cv::COLOR_HLS2BGR = 60,
  cv::COLOR_HLS2RGB = 61,
  cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL = 66,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2HSV_FULL = 67,
  cv::COLOR_BGR2HLS_FULL = 68,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2HLS_FULL = 69,
  cv::COLOR_HSV2BGR_FULL = 70,
  cv::COLOR_HSV2RGB_FULL = 71,
  cv::COLOR_HLS2BGR_FULL = 72,
  cv::COLOR_HLS2RGB_FULL = 73,
  cv::COLOR_LBGR2Lab = 74,
  cv::COLOR_LRGB2Lab = 75,
  cv::COLOR_LBGR2Luv = 76,
  cv::COLOR_LRGB2Luv = 77,
  cv::COLOR_Lab2LBGR = 78,
  cv::COLOR_Lab2LRGB = 79,
  cv::COLOR_Luv2LBGR = 80,
  cv::COLOR_Luv2LRGB = 81,
  cv::COLOR_BGR2YUV = 82,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2YUV = 83,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR = 84,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGB = 85,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV12 = 90,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV12 = 91,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV21 = 92,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV21 = 93,
  cv::COLOR_YUV420sp2RGB = COLOR_YUV2RGB_NV21,
  cv::COLOR_YUV420sp2BGR = COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV21,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV12 = 94,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGRA_NV12 = 95,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21 = 96,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGRA_NV21 = 97,
  cv::COLOR_YUV420sp2RGBA = COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21,
  cv::COLOR_YUV420sp2BGRA = COLOR_YUV2BGRA_NV21,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGB_YV12 = 98,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_YV12 = 99,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGB_IYUV = 100,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_IYUV = 101,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGB_I420 = COLOR_YUV2RGB_IYUV,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_I420 = COLOR_YUV2BGR_IYUV,
  cv::COLOR_YUV420p2RGB = COLOR_YUV2RGB_YV12,
  cv::COLOR_YUV420p2BGR = COLOR_YUV2BGR_YV12,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGBA_YV12 = 102,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGRA_YV12 = 103,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGBA_IYUV = 104,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGRA_IYUV = 105,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGBA_I420 = COLOR_YUV2RGBA_IYUV,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGRA_I420 = COLOR_YUV2BGRA_IYUV,
  cv::COLOR_YUV420p2RGBA = COLOR_YUV2RGBA_YV12,
  cv::COLOR_YUV420p2BGRA = COLOR_YUV2BGRA_YV12,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2GRAY_420 = 106,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2GRAY_NV21 = COLOR_YUV2GRAY_420,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2GRAY_NV12 = COLOR_YUV2GRAY_420,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2GRAY_YV12 = COLOR_YUV2GRAY_420,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2GRAY_IYUV = COLOR_YUV2GRAY_420,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2GRAY_I420 = COLOR_YUV2GRAY_420,
  cv::COLOR_YUV420sp2GRAY = COLOR_YUV2GRAY_420,
  cv::COLOR_YUV420p2GRAY = COLOR_YUV2GRAY_420,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGB_UYVY = 107,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_UYVY = 108,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGB_Y422 = COLOR_YUV2RGB_UYVY,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_Y422 = COLOR_YUV2BGR_UYVY,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGB_UYNV = COLOR_YUV2RGB_UYVY,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_UYNV = COLOR_YUV2BGR_UYVY,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGBA_UYVY = 111,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGRA_UYVY = 112,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGBA_Y422 = COLOR_YUV2RGBA_UYVY,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGRA_Y422 = COLOR_YUV2BGRA_UYVY,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGBA_UYNV = COLOR_YUV2RGBA_UYVY,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGRA_UYNV = COLOR_YUV2BGRA_UYVY,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGB_YUY2 = 115,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_YUY2 = 116,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGB_YVYU = 117,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_YVYU = 118,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGB_YUYV = COLOR_YUV2RGB_YUY2,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_YUYV = COLOR_YUV2BGR_YUY2,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGB_YUNV = COLOR_YUV2RGB_YUY2,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_YUNV = COLOR_YUV2BGR_YUY2,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGBA_YUY2 = 119,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGRA_YUY2 = 120,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGBA_YVYU = 121,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGRA_YVYU = 122,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGBA_YUYV = COLOR_YUV2RGBA_YUY2,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGRA_YUYV = COLOR_YUV2BGRA_YUY2,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2RGBA_YUNV = COLOR_YUV2RGBA_YUY2,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2BGRA_YUNV = COLOR_YUV2BGRA_YUY2,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2GRAY_UYVY = 123,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2GRAY_YUY2 = 124,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2GRAY_Y422 = COLOR_YUV2GRAY_UYVY,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2GRAY_UYNV = COLOR_YUV2GRAY_UYVY,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2GRAY_YVYU = COLOR_YUV2GRAY_YUY2,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2GRAY_YUYV = COLOR_YUV2GRAY_YUY2,
  cv::COLOR_YUV2GRAY_YUNV = COLOR_YUV2GRAY_YUY2,
  cv::COLOR_RGBA2mRGBA = 125,
  cv::COLOR_mRGBA2RGBA = 126,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2YUV_I420 = 127,
  cv::COLOR_BGR2YUV_I420 = 128,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2YUV_IYUV = COLOR_RGB2YUV_I420,
  cv::COLOR_BGR2YUV_IYUV = COLOR_BGR2YUV_I420,
  cv::COLOR_RGBA2YUV_I420 = 129,
  cv::COLOR_BGRA2YUV_I420 = 130,
  cv::COLOR_RGBA2YUV_IYUV = COLOR_RGBA2YUV_I420,
  cv::COLOR_BGRA2YUV_IYUV = COLOR_BGRA2YUV_I420,
  cv::COLOR_RGB2YUV_YV12 = 131,
  cv::COLOR_BGR2YUV_YV12 = 132,
  cv::COLOR_RGBA2YUV_YV12 = 133,
  cv::COLOR_BGRA2YUV_YV12 = 134,
  cv::COLOR_BayerBG2BGR = 46,
  cv::COLOR_BayerGB2BGR = 47,
  cv::COLOR_BayerRG2BGR = 48,
  cv::COLOR_BayerGR2BGR = 49,
  cv::COLOR_BayerBG2RGB = COLOR_BayerRG2BGR,
  cv::COLOR_BayerGB2RGB = COLOR_BayerGR2BGR,
  cv::COLOR_BayerRG2RGB = COLOR_BayerBG2BGR,
  cv::COLOR_BayerGR2RGB = COLOR_BayerGB2BGR,
  cv::COLOR_BayerBG2GRAY = 86,
  cv::COLOR_BayerGB2GRAY = 87,
  cv::COLOR_BayerRG2GRAY = 88,
  cv::COLOR_BayerGR2GRAY = 89,
  cv::COLOR_BayerBG2BGR_VNG = 62,
  cv::COLOR_BayerGB2BGR_VNG = 63,
  cv::COLOR_BayerRG2BGR_VNG = 64,
  cv::COLOR_BayerGR2BGR_VNG = 65,
  cv::COLOR_BayerBG2RGB_VNG = COLOR_BayerRG2BGR_VNG,
  cv::COLOR_BayerGB2RGB_VNG = COLOR_BayerGR2BGR_VNG,
  cv::COLOR_BayerRG2RGB_VNG = COLOR_BayerBG2BGR_VNG,
  cv::COLOR_BayerGR2RGB_VNG = COLOR_BayerGB2BGR_VNG,
  cv::COLOR_BayerBG2BGR_EA = 135,
  cv::COLOR_BayerGB2BGR_EA = 136,
  cv::COLOR_BayerRG2BGR_EA = 137,
  cv::COLOR_BayerGR2BGR_EA = 138,
  cv::COLOR_BayerBG2RGB_EA = COLOR_BayerRG2BGR_EA,
  cv::COLOR_BayerGB2RGB_EA = COLOR_BayerGR2BGR_EA,
  cv::COLOR_BayerRG2RGB_EA = COLOR_BayerBG2BGR_EA,
  cv::COLOR_BayerGR2RGB_EA = COLOR_BayerGB2BGR_EA,
  cv::COLOR_BayerBG2BGRA = 139,
  cv::COLOR_BayerGB2BGRA = 140,
  cv::COLOR_BayerRG2BGRA = 141,
  cv::COLOR_BayerGR2BGRA = 142,
  cv::COLOR_BayerBG2RGBA = COLOR_BayerRG2BGRA,
  cv::COLOR_BayerGB2RGBA = COLOR_BayerGR2BGRA,
  cv::COLOR_BayerRG2RGBA = COLOR_BayerBG2BGRA,
  cv::COLOR_BayerGR2RGBA = COLOR_BayerGB2BGRA,
  cv::COLOR_COLORCVT_MAX = 143
}
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please select it as the answer by clicking the green checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

this solved,i added a subsidiary function referencing the archive view

```
class MonthlySum(RedirectView):
def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
    today = timezone.now()
    return reverse(
        'month-archive',
        kwargs={
            
            'month': today.month,
            'year': today.year,
        }
    )
```

in the URLs

```
path('offering/report/<int:year>/<int:month>/',views.OfferingMonthArchiveView.as_view(),name="month-archive"),
```